# Change the results of a list into a dataframe

Tags: r

From this process:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httpuv)
library(httr)

i<-1
results3 <- list();
for (a in 1:2) {
    getURL = paste0("https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=sentimentcommitter-date:2000-01-01..2023-01-20&sort=committer-date&order=asc&per_page=100&page=",a)
    req <- GET(getURL)
    data <- content(req)
    results3[[i]] <- data$items
    i <- i + 1
    print(i)
}
```

How is it possible to convert the reuslt of list results3 into a dataframe which 200 rows and 117 columns as it is here `df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(results_json, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE, flatten = TRUE)` and `length(df$items[[1]])`

Comment: Is there anthing additional I should clarrify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a little bit weird. But making a `json` first which is then flattened and then binding them to a DF brings the desired result.

```
js <- jsonlite::toJSON(results3)
df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(js, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE, flatten = TRUE)

ddf <- rbind(df[[1]], df[[2]])

class(ddf)
# [1] "data.frame"
dim(ddf)
# [1] 200 117
```

---

**Update**
To your comment: you can also use `bind_rows` from `dplyr`:

```
ddf <- df |> bind_rows()

class(ddf)
#[1] "data.frame"

dim(ddf)
#[1] 200 117
```

Comment: Thank you, if there are more option and not only 2 is it possible to make this modification?

Comment: Yes, it should work for more options. You have to adopt `rbind`.

Comment: Thank you but if I have 300 cases of df[[i]] how should I write in order not to have the 300 cases

Comment: @`Erik Brole`: I have updated my answer with an alternative way `bind_rows()`

Answer (score 0):

`per_page=10` for testing (i.e. 20 rows in total), *jsonlite* can handle urls by itself too :

```r
url <- "https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=sentimentcommitter-date:2000-01-01..2023-01-20&sort=committer-date&order=asc&per_page=10&page="
commits <- lapply(1:2, 
                  \(page) jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0(url, page), 
                                             simplifyVector =TRUE, 
                                             flatten = TRUE)$items) |>
  do.call(rbind, args = _)
```

Results:

```r
tibble::glimpse(commits)
#> Rows: 20
#> Columns: 117
#> $ url                                  <chr> "https://api.github.com/repos/dsp…
#> $ sha                                  <chr> "e8f884162cbba5c890bec7a002a9e758…
#> $ node_id                              <chr> "MDY6Q29tbWl0MTQ1OTE2NzM4OmU4Zjg4…
#> $ html_url                             <chr> "https://github.com/dspinellis/li…
#> $ comments_url                         <chr> "https://api.github.com/repos/dsp…
#> $ parents                              <list> [<data.frame[1 x 3]>], [<data.fr…
#> $ score                                <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, …
#> $ commit.url                           <chr> "https://api.github.com/repos/dsp…
#> $ commit.message                       <chr> "USB HCD: avoid duplicate local_i…
#> ...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>